# New installation Shower room has sewer smell. Flushing toilet causes gurgling & vacuum in shower drain

Tags: shower, floor, ground

Newly Installed ground floor Shower room has sewer smell.Flushing toilet causes gurgling & vacuum in shower drain

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. When you take the [tour] you'll note that this is a _Question_ and Answer site, so it would be good to [edit] your question to actually ask a question. Also, we're going to need a lot more information about your installation - some pictures and details of the plumbing (for instance, is the plumbing properly vented?) will be really useful to help us help you.

Comment: Get your plumber back to make it right. Assuming a plumber installed it.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like there's a missing vent or a clogged vent between the toilet and the shower. Flushing the toilet sucks the water out of the shower trap and allows sewer gas to enter through the shower. If a contractor did the job, get them back to fix it. If it was a DIY job, check the venting.

Comment: There is a vent& it is not clogged. I wonder was the drain laid with the correct gradient?

Comment: Do you know the exact location of the vent?  Were traps installed in the shower?  Won't knnow about the correct gradient unless you rip up some stuff.

Comment: The plumber that did the work is coming tomorrow. I hope  that there is a solution other than digging up the floor The distance between the shower & the toilet outlet pipe is 1.4m (59")